# Trouble with align and text going off the page

Tags: align

I am having problems using `align`. I would like my equations and text to all line up. The first equation is displayed fine, but the next few go off the side of the page. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}    
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}    
\begin{document}  

\begin{align}
P(p_{i}, \pi, \theta| data) \propto \prod_{i} P(data| p_{i}, n)\times P(p_{i}|\pi,\theta)\times P(\pi)\times P(\theta)\\
\text{where} & P(p_{i}, \pi, \theta| data) & \text{is the \textbf{posterior} distribution}\\
\text{where} & P(data| p_{i}, n) \sim Binomial(p, n=10^{6}) & \text{ is the \textbf{Likliehood}}\\  
\text{where} & P(p_{i}|\pi,\theta) \sim Beta(\pi\theta, (1-\pi)\theta)\\
\text{where} & P(\pi) \sim Beta(1,1) & \text{ is the initial \textbf{prior} distribution}\\
\text{where} & P(\theta) \sim Uniform(10^{-3}, 10^{4}) & \text{ is the distribution used to draw samples of \textbf{precision} for the Beta distribution}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

This code is giving me something like this:
[image]

But I would like it all to stay within the page.

Comment: How exactly should they line up? It's not strange that you get that result, there are no alignment points (`&`) in the first line, so everything is placed in the first column.

Comment: That's a great point. I didn't realize that alignment points mattered between lines. I thought they only mattered within lines.

Comment: Of course they do. The whole point is to align for example `=` in consecutive lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following may be what you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}    
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}    
\begin{document}  

\begin{align}
&P(p_{i}, \pi, \theta\mid \text{data}) \propto \prod_{i} P(\text{data}\mid  p_{i}, n)\times P(p_{i}\mid \pi,\theta)\times P(\pi)\times P(\theta)\\
\shortintertext{where}
&P(p_{i}, \pi, \theta\mid\text{data}) \text{ is the \textbf{posterior} distribution}\\
&P(\text{data}\mid  p_{i}, n) \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(p, n=10^{6}) \text{ is the \textbf{likelihood}}\\  
&P(p_{i}\mid \pi,\theta) \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\pi\theta, (1-\pi)\theta)\\
&P(\pi) \sim \mathrm{Beta}(1,1) \text{ is the initial \textbf{prior} distribution}\\
&P(\theta) \sim \parbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}{$\mathrm{Uniform}(10^{-3}, 10^{4})$ is the distribution used to draw samples of \textbf{precision} for the Beta distribution}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Assigning equation numbers to the explanatory lines may not be needed or desirable. If this hunch is correct, the following solution may be preferable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}    
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}    
\begin{document}  

\begin{equation}
P(p_{i}, \pi, \theta\mid \text{data}) \propto \prod_{i} P(\text{data}\mid  p_{i}, n)\times P(p_{i}\mid \pi,\theta)\times P(\pi)\times P(\theta)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
&P(p_{i}, \pi, \theta\mid\text{data}) \text{ is the \textbf{posterior} distribution}\\
&P(\text{data}\mid  p_{i}, n) \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(p, n=10^{6}) \text{ is the \textbf{likelihood}}\\  
&P(p_{i}\mid \pi,\theta) \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\pi\theta, (1-\pi)\theta)\\
&P(\pi) \sim \mathrm{Beta}(1,1) \text{ is the initial \textbf{prior} distribution}\\
&P(\theta) \sim \parbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}{$\mathrm{Uniform}(10^{-3}, 10^{4})$ is the distribution used to draw samples of \textbf{precision} for the Beta distribution}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose this simple code, since there's nothing really to align in the equation, I use a `gather` environment, and `tabularx` and `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx, enumitem}

\begin{document}


\begin{gather}
P(p_{i}, \pi, \theta \mid \text{data}) \propto \prod _{i} P(\mathrm{data}\mid p_{i}, n) \times P(p_{i}\mid \pi,\theta ) \times P(\pi ) \times P(\theta )\\
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\quad}|X@{\qquad}}
where & \begin{description}[itemsep = 0pt,topsep = 0pt, before={\leavevmode\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep\relax}}, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]%
    \item[$ P(p_{i}, \pi, \theta\mid \mathrm{data})$] is the \textbf{posterior} distribution, %
    \item[$ P(\mathrm{data}\mid p_{i}, n) \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(p, n=10^{6}) $] is the \textbf{likelihood}, %
    \item[$ P(p_{i}\mid \pi, \theta) \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\pi\theta, (1- \pi)\theta) $,] %
    \item[$ P(\pi) \sim \mathrm{Beta}(1,1) $] is the initial \textbf{prior} distribution, %
    \item[$ P(\theta) \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(10^{-3}, 10^{4})$] is the distribution used to draw samples of \textbf{precision} for the Beta distribution.%
\end{description}
\end{tabularx}\notag
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Done. Thank you for pointing it. I often copy the code from the screen, and my editor displays some commands as symbols symbols for better legibility.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Just splitting the `align` equations up works.

```
\begin{equation}
P(p_{i}, \pi, \theta| data) \propto \prod_{i} P(data| p_{i},     n)*P(p_{i}|\pi,\theta)*P(\pi)*P(\theta)
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
\text{where} & P(p_{i}, \pi, \theta| data) & \text{is the \textbf{posterior} distribution}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{where} & P(data| p_{i}, n) \sim Binomial(p, n=10^{6}) & \text{ is the \textbf{Likliehood}} 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{where} & P(p_{i}|\pi,\theta) \sim Beta(\pi\theta, (1-\pi)\theta)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{where} & P(\pi) \sim Beta(1,1) & \text{ is the initial \textbf{prior} distribution}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{where} & P(\theta) \sim Uniform(10^{-3}, 10^{4}) & \text{ is the distribution used to draw samples of \textbf{precision} for the Beta    distribution}
\end{align}
```

Comment: This really isn't a recommended way of doing that, you get a lot of extra whitespace.  Try with your original code, remove all the `&` and replace `align` with `gather`.